# How use "LIKE" and "%" to check similarity to variable in android(Java code)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-like

I am working on Android app using Java, I need to query database in Java code to check if userinput(variable) statement is contain words which are in my SQLite DataBase using `LIKE` in query and `rowQuery` method in java code,

I used this code but it did not work:

> ```
> cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT shompet FROM sentence WHERE " + column + " LIKE '%"
>                               + newMessage + "%'", null);
> ```

`newMessage` is my variable(userInput)

I read similar topics but either they are not my answer or they are so complicated.

Comment: Beware [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: What is the value of `newMessage`? What is the database value that you think should match?

Comment: @cl. It's simple string like "hi there" or "how are you" and so on, and in database we have values like "hi" which match for "hi there" and "are" which match "how are you"

Comment: @GriffeyDog. there are good examples but no example for using "Like"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression `'hi' LIKE '%hi there%'`, it is not possible to find *any* characters to replace the `%` wildcards so that the strings would match.

You need to do the comparison the other way around, i.e., `'hi there' LIKE '%hi%'`:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT shompet FROM sentence" +
            " WHERE ? LIKE '%' || " + column + " || '%'",
            new String[] { newMessage });
```

Comment: @CL.Thanks, your solution worked for me great.but i can't understand your code completely, can you please explain what is "?" after WHERE and what is "||" ?

Comment: @CL.do you know any useful doc for learning and training SQLite?

Comment: `?` is a parameter, which allows you to put values into SQL commands without having to format them; this prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/). In SQL, `||` concatenates strings.

Comment: '@CL.thanks for your great help, and nice page [link](http://xkcd.com/327/) with nice example.