# how get max length of records in a column and use it to check equality in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am developing an chatbot app using sqlite, chatbot is a program which simulate human vs human Chatting!
in my app, user type something as input and i use it as variable in my JAVA and SQLite query,
for example consider this table:

### id   -     user        -           chatbot

1    -    how          -     is it important to know how
2    -   how are you   -     i am fine

i use this code to get proper answer from DB:
(which is from this topic: [How use “LIKE” and “%” to check similarity to variable in android(Java code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407287/how-use-like-and-to-check-similarity-to-variable-in-androidjava-code)

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT chatbot FROM sentence"+ 
                     " WHERE ? LIKE '%' || " + USER + " || '%'"
                      ,new String[] { newMessage });
```

this code work fine in most cases but in cases like this,it doesn't work: when user type in input how are you it select "i am fine" which is correct asnwer but unfortunately select "is it important to know how" too,

I used this code to only choose records with maximum length of user column:

```
cursor = db .rawQuery( "SELECT shompet FROM sentence" +
                 "WHERE LENGTH(user) = SELECT MAX(LENGTH(user)) from sentence "
                 + " WHERE ? LIKE '%' || " + USER + " || '%'", new String[] {
                 newMessage });
```

but when i run it on simulator, it close and show this " app has stopped",
i think it has syntax error,

please help me to correct this syntax or give me another way to handle this problem, waiting for your advice!

Comment: add the log from the error

Comment: @Srinath Ganesh Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT chatbot FROM sentenceWHERE LENGTH(user) = SELECT MAX(LENGTH(user)) from sentence WHERE ? LIKE '%' || user || '%'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make use of an **inner** query like this.

```
SELECT chatbot, user
FROM sentence
WHERE LENGTH(user) = (
  SELECT MAX(LENGTH(user))
  FROM sentence
  WHERE 'not exactly' LIKE '%' || user || '%'
) AND 'not exactly' LIKE '%' || user || '%'
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cb15a/3) Output:

```
+------------+-------------+
|  CHATBOT   |    USER     |
+------------+-------------+
| why not    | not exactly |
+------------+-------------+
```

So, you need to create your `cursor` as

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT chatbot FROM sentence " + 
                     "WHERE LENGTH(user) = ( " +
                     " SELECT MAX(LENGTH(user)) FROM sentence " +
                     "  WHERE ? LIKE '%' || " + USER + " || '%' " +
                     ") AND ? LIKE '%' || " + USER + " || '%' ",
                     new String[] { newMessage, newMessage });
```

Comment: there is another problem when i run your query,suppose we add this record "(3, 'not exactly', 'why not')" , why query, select this record too?    [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cc0f/1)

Comment: what's the user input?

Comment: i tested this many times, it seems that this query just consider equality of length and ignore this part [WHERE ? LIKE '%' || " + USER + " || '%' "],

Comment: user input is a simple string like "how are you",

Comment: i think that i got the point: we should add this part to first select too, it would be like this: SELECT chatbot, user
FROM sentence
WHERE LENGTH(user) = (
  SELECT MAX(len)
  FROM (
    SELECT LENGTH(user) as len
    FROM sentence
    WHERE 'how are you' LIKE '%' || user || '%'
  ) AS s
) AND 'how are you' LIKE '%' || user || '%'

Comment: SQLite says no such function : CONCAT , your first solution is fine, just add this part at the end, i edited your first part of code, how can i convert it to use in Android(java),(implementing cursor)?

Comment: Please test the new query. It works now with your new data. Basically you need the LIKE check for outer query as well.

Comment: Ah, okay it works for SQLite. I changed to `CONCAT()` because I was testing on MySQL. Please, try with `||` instead. It should work now.

Comment: a question related to CONCAT() .
quoting the accepted answer
"The best way in my eyes is to use the concat() method provided by the String class itself.

The useage would, in your case, look like this:

String myConcatedString = cursor.getString(numcol).concat('-').
       concat(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(db.KEY_DESTINATIE)));"

: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244307/concatenate-two-strings

Comment: @MehrdadSalimi Thanks. I learned about SQLite too. Gave you a +1 for that.

Comment: @Ravi Thapliyal , right now i have not enough reputation to +1 your post, when i got enough, i will, your solution was what exactly i want.

Answer (score 1):

if your application gets more big then a simple SQL may get confused due to

- missing userinput
- multiple matches

so i would suggest this

table: indices(id,values-unique)

table: quest(qid,indices)

table: ans(qid,aid,text)

```
  indices
-------------
id     values
1      how
2      are
3      you



 quest
-------------
qid    ids
1      1,2,3
2      1



ans
-------------
aid qid text
1   1   it is...
2   2   i am...
```

---

1. input: user text
2. break up into parts
3. get indices(id from indices table)
4. lookup quest table
5. lookup ans table

Comment: thanks, i think my DB and tables getting more and more complicated, i will keep in mind your advises, i didn't know so much about indexing.

Comment: @MehrdadSalimi no manual indexing is done (primary key for id,qid,aid creates implicit index and it manages it itself -no programmer care needed )

Comment: i thought that what you did is indexing! :) ,anyway,your method for implementing separate tables for question and answer will make coding and making query easier, but more time to fill tables!i will try it.